# Opsworks NodeJs app restarting with SIGTERM every 120 seconds

Tags: node.js, aws-opsworks

We have a NodeJS app that is restarting every N seconds without any apparent cause.

Logs from app are looking correctly from configured health check URL on Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

After trying to start app from command line instead of relying on Opsworks to do that we found out that `SIGTERM` signal was being sent by `monit`.

Logs on `/var/messages` showed that monit was trying to use `/` as url for TCP health check while ELB were trying `/health`. As root path had nothing on our app it was being restarted every 120 seconds

Answer (score 1):

OpsWorks configures monit for NodeJs apps and hardcodes a check to path `/`. We could not find documentation about this but is evident on actual code:

- https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/master-chef-11.10/opsworks_nodejs/templates/default/node_web_app.monitrc.erb

Our solution involved :

- putting empty content to root path `/` with status `200` to let monit know process is up. (Shallow health check)
- our old health path with more elaborate reporting and status `200` or `500` to know if required resources by process are needed. (Deep health check)

This might not work for every case as we were using specific endpoints for our scenario and had no original use for `/`.